# Node JS app running at the same time as express api with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, service

What I'm trying to do:
I have a small Node app makes a request to an API to get data about the stock market and then saves the data to a Mongo DB (already made and working), which I would like to run constantly. Next I need to build an API which allows my other servers/apps to get that data being (not made yet).

I think Express is a good choice although I know there are other options. I am getting this code from another API that I built for a MEAN stack app and have been looking around to troubleshoot.

My main issue is that most tutorials show how to just build a CRUD API for the MEAN, MERN, and other stacks. I'm not really sure how to structure this system or Node apps can run independently of one another in the way that I am describing.

Currently I am not getting any errors when I run the app but I am not able to get anything when I go to my endpoints.

When I first started I thought that the standalone Node app (request and writing data part of this) could live within the same file as the Express part, but now I don't think that would work and have split those into separate files. I have seen PM2 and other ways of making the node app into a background service?

Not totally sure, some clarification on that, as well as some help with why my express API endpoints won't respond with data from the database. Here is my code.

**Standalone app:**

```
const request = require('request');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const d = new Date();
let day = d.getDay()
let hour = d.getHours();

const stockMomentSchema = new Schema({
    symbol: String,
    price: Number,
    size: Number,
    time: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

const StockMoment = mongoose.model('stockMoment', stockMomentSchema, 'stockPriceData');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/stock-test')
    .then(() => {
        console.log('connected');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });

function makeRequest() {
    if(day <= 1 || day >= 5) {
        if(hour >= 10 || hour <= 15) {
            getMarketData();
        }
    }
}

function getMarketData() {
    request({
        url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/tops/last',
        json: true
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
            const stockMoment = new StockMoment({
                symbol: body[i].symbol,
                price: body[i].price,
                size: body[i].size,
                time: body[i].time,
            });
            stockMoment.save((err) => {
                if(err) return handleError(err);
                console.log('Saved!', i);
            });
            console.log(body[i]);
        }
    });
}


makeRequest();

//setInterval(makeRequest, 5000);
```

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path'); // Not sure if this is needed
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const api = require('./api');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cors());

//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'))); // Not sure if this is needed

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.status(404);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen('3000', function() {
    console.log('--------------------');
    console.log('Server running');
    console.log('You can view the server at http://localhost:3000');
    console.log('If you are running an Angular app on while using this server please use http://localhost:4200');
    console.log('--------------------');
});
```

**stock model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const StockSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    phoneNumber: {type: String, required: true},
    company: {type: String, required: true},
    about: {type: String, required: true},
    userType: {type: String, required: true}
});

StockSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Stock', StockSchema);
```

**api.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Stock = require('./stock.js');

router.get('/', function(req, res, err) {
    console.log('Hello world');
});


router.get('/stocks/:id', function(req, res, err) {
    console.log('Hello world');
    const stockData = {
        _id: false,
        symbol: true,
        price: true,
        size: true,
        time: true
    }
    Stock.findById(req.params.id, stockData, function(err, stock) {
        if(err) {
            res.send('No stocks found');
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(stock);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Edit:**
Added mongoose.connect to server.js but it still doesn't work

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/stock-test')
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('connected');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Here's a gist with the working changes https://gist.github.com/drGrove/3e6699ded09f282e528a661fb41439e1

Your api is pulling in a schema that has no information associated with it. 
You should break out the StockMomentData, `require` it from you api.js and use that in your get request by id instead of your current `stock` model.

Since your mongoose connection is shared between the two "applications" you can pull that out into a db.js and just require that file on load for each project (But that can always be done at a later time).

Just note that you do need a connection in either your Model file or your api.js file so that mongoose actually connects to the mongo database

Initial Answer: 
Your API server is missing a connection to Mongo via mongoose. You'll have to have a connection call just like what you have in your "standalone app".

Comment: So just adding this `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/stock-test')`? That doesn't seem to work

Comment: Thank you so much for doing all that, I understand what what you're getting at however it still doesn't work. I am not getting any errors, but when I try to visit one of my endpoints it just hangs and doesn't do anything

Comment: Actually your answer worked, thank you! I was just over looking something the whole time.